Diya during parayana
Hi Is it compulsory for one light up a diya throughout saptashati Parayana or any other parayana? Can diya not be lighted at all during parayana even at home?
Also can one sit on a chair to do the parayan if can't sit cross legged for long?

Seems like Sri Chandi or Saptashati needs initiation, so guru can guide. It any spiritual practice Diya is recommended as per I read.
